# project euler number 35: circular prime understandability

Tags: primes

http://projecteuler.net/problem=35

The problem says that the number 197 is a circular prime since all rotations of its digits are prime.

Well as per my understanding all rotations of `197` are `197, 971, 719, 179, 917, 791` and out of which `917` and `791` are not prime.

Then how is 197 a circular prime?
Why only 3 of the rotations are considered and the rest 3 are left out?
Am I missing something here?

Thanks!!

Comment: 791, 917 and 179 are NOT rotations of the number. Those numbers are swapped, not rotated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not make permutations. Make rotations. Only rotate the digits. They have to stay in their order, you can't swap two.

Therefore, the rotations of `197` are `197`, `971` and `719`. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You have listed permutations of 197. Rotations are achieved by shifting, so the only rotations of 197 are 719 and 971